# Change in the requirements - store 2 different values in a single database table field

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table with a field which is an `unsigned tinyint` (max value: 255).

Typical change in the requirements. We would need to create a new field because of a bunch of records in that table. But that would be very expensive for the application (lots of changes, a lot of work).

So we are thinking to combine the new value with the old value.

Basically in an `unsigned tinyint` (max value: 255), we need to store:

- an integer that can be 1, 2, 3 or 4
- an integer that can span from 1 to 30 (limits included)

The requirement is to get and set the 'combined' value with an algorithm as easy as possible.

How would you do that?
If possible I would like not to use any binary representation.

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use multiples of 32 to represent 1-4 and add the 1-30 on top.
[1,1] would be 33
[1,2] would be 34
[1,30] would be 62
[2,1] would be 65
[2,30] would be 94
[4,1] would be 129
[4,30] would be 158

This would work and be unambiguous, but in general I really think you should not consort to a hack like this. Add the column and change your code. What will you do with the next requirements change? At the end, your software will be a collection of hacks and it can't be maintained anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Let's call the two values x and y.

While storing the numbers perform these steps:

1. Multiply x by 100.
2. Add the result of 1 to y.
3. Store the result of 2 in the column.

Thus, if x were to be 3, and y 15, I would get 315 for the result. You can decode that easily by first extracting the last two digits from the number and then dividing by 100 will give you the first one.

But because you have to fit the numbers within 255, you can chose an appropriate multiplier that is less than 100.

Comment: Looks like I was too fast. In essence, now you are saying the same than me ;)